# Spring ws - AxiomSoapMessage & attachment with MTOM are inline

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, axiom

im trying to understand how the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` handles request (the body & attachment) but i dont understand some points (or they are maybe features)

i 'm using `AxioSoapMessageFactory` like this :

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="payloadCaching" value="true"/>
    <property name="attachmentCaching" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Here is the point :

I have thought that the `AxiomSoapMessage` will contain :

- the `SoapMessage` in the `axiomMessage` property like in my request
- the attachment in the `attachments` property.This one is stored in a temp directory thanks to (`attachmentCaching=true`)

But the attachment is intead inline See [this screenshot](http://data.imagup.com/3/1288351287.JPG)

So **why is the attachment inline like here** ? Is what any interceptor will see ? What is the benefit of have an attachment inline if the `attachmentCaching` (see above) was set to true ?

I know i should ask this on the Spring forum but it seems almost death concerning answers. 
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the property attachmentCaching in AxiomSoapMessageFactory only being used if the soap message has content type as Multipart message.  So how do I get my client to send Multipart message with attachment in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mtom attachments in the Marshaller (by default it's disabled in Jaxb2Marshaller)